# How do you use a locator map?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

How do you use these locator maps? I've been using them for a while, but I don't get it. Could someone help me?

Comment: Note "locator map" is a Bedrock Edition item name - the same item in JE is just called 'map'. In BE 'map' (crafted with only paper) doesn't have these extra features (and this sort of maps is inaccessible in JE).

Comment: I forgot. Sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Locator maps show where all players are on a map (indicated by colored arrow-like shapes) that point in the player's facing direction. If someone is on the edge of a map, that means they are not in the area of the map.

Player 1 is always indicated by a **white shape**, as seen below.

[image: Locator Map]

When placed in an item frame, a **lime shape** will be added corresponding to the item frame's position. This marker will only be shown on its own map and will always point north (upwards).

Placing a banner down and right-clicking it with the map will add a **banner marker** with it's correct color.

[image: Bannered Map]

Comment: holy hecc i had no idea you could have banners on maps wow thank you so much